# JS Performing actions on a popup window

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

So lately I have been learning JS and trying to interact with webpages, scraping at first but now also doing interactions on a specific webpage.
For instance, I have a webpage that contains a button, I want to press this button roughly every 30 seconds and then it refreshes (and the countdown starts again). I wrote to following script to do this:

```
var klikCount = 0;
function getPlayElement() {
    var playElement = document.querySelector('.button_red');
    return playElement;
}
function doKlik() {
    var playElement = getPlayElement();
    klikCount++;
    console.log('Watched ' + klikCount);
    playElement.click();
    setTimeout(doKlik, 30000);
}
doKlik()
```

But now I need to step up my game, and every time I click the button a new window pops up and I need to perform an action in there too, then close it and go back to the 'main' script.
Is this possible through JS? Please keep in mind I am a total javascript noob and not aware of a lot of basic functionality.

Thank you, 
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOM events have an `isTrusted` property that is `true` only when the event has been generated by the user, instead of synthetically, as it is for the `el.click()` case.

The *popup* is one of the numerous Web mechanism that works only if the click, or similar action, has been performed by the user, not the code itself.

Giving a page the ability to open infinite amount of popups has never been a great idea so that very long time ago they killed the feature in many ways.

You could, in your own tab/window, create iframes and perform actions within these frames through [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage), but I'm not sure that's good enough for you.

Regardless, the code that would work if the click was generated from the user, is something like the following:

```
document.body.addEventListener(
  'click',
  event => {
    const outer = open(
      'about:blank',
      'blanka',
      'menubar=no,location=yes,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,status=yes'
    );
    outer.document.open();
    outer.document.write('This is a pretty big popup!');
    // post a message to the opener (aka current window)
    outer.document.write(
      '<script>opener.postMessage("O hi Mark!", "*");</script>'
    );
    // set a timer to close the popup
    outer.document.write(
      '<script>setTimeout(close, 1000)</script>'
    );
    outer.document.close();
    // you could also outer.close()
    // instead of waiting the timeout
  }
);

// will receive the message and log
// "O hi Mark!"
addEventListener('message', event => {
  console.log(event.data);
});
```

Every popup has an opener, and every different window can communicate via `postMessage`.

You can read [more about window.open in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open).